# C# - filling in empty dates in a collection

Tags: c#

Assume that the class **Data** is defined as **{DateTime TransactionDate, int ItemCount}**.
I get an original IEnumerable containing scattered TransactionDates and ItemCounts and I need to write a method that returns a collection with all the days filled in between the minimum and the maximum days in the original collection.

For instance, if I get:
12/5/2009 15.00 
12/7/2009 10.00 
12/10/2009 75.00

I need to generate something like this:
12/5/2009 15.00 
12/6/2009 0.00 
12/7/2009 10.00 
12/8/2009 0.00 
12/9/2009 0.00 
12/10/2009 75.00

Get you give me an elegant way of doing this with c# 3.0?

I have a list of all dates between the minimum and maximum dates. So I assume all I have to do is "foreach" the intersect collection (allDates-existingDates) and insert a new element for each of these. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extension method that should do the job. It's purely based on iterators (`IEnumerable<Data>`), so it would seem quite a nice approach to me.

```
public static IEnumerable<Data> FillIn(this IEnumerable<Data> original)
{
    Data lastItem = null;
    foreach (var item in original)
    {
        if (lastItem != null)
        {
            var fakeItem = new DateTime(lastItem.TransactionDate.Year,
                lastItem.TransactionDate.Month, lastItem.TransactionDate.Day)
                .AddDays(1);
            while (fakeItem.TransactionDate != item.TransactionDate)
            {
                yield return fakeItem;
                fakeItem.TransactionDate = fakeItem.TransactionDate.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
        lastItem = item;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Where `Data` is simply defined as:

```
class Data
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate;
    public int ItemCount;
}
```

Comment: You should consider the fact that AddDays works on floats. For that reason I've found it not to be accurate sometimes (i.e. adding 23h59mXXs and not one day).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your collection is a dictionary (dates are unique and can be used as keys), you could do something lik this:

-1. Determinie the first and last date in your source collection (if the collection is a sortedDictionary you have first and last elements).

-2. Create a IEnumerator that can iterate trough all dates between a given start and end date.

-3. Use a foreach structure, using the Enumerator and the obtained start and end dates you gathered. At each step, check if the current date is a key in the source list, in which case you copy it in the result list, otherwise create a new result item with the current date and 0 for item count.

Let me know of this proof-of-concept is enought for you, if not I will try to build an example.

**Edit:** You edited your question, mentionig you already have the list of all dates between the start and end so you can skip the 2nd step. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a List containing all dates in the range from minimum date to maximum date called alldates, you can do the following:

```
var transactions = new List<Data>(originalData);
transactions.AddRange(from dt in
                      alldates.Except
                          (
                          from t in transactions
                          select t.TransactionDate
                          )
                  select new Data() { TransactionDate = dt, ItemCount = 0 });
```

where Data is defined as:

```
class Data
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) from the first date and fill in the blanks while looping from first to last date?